# How to get Username & Avatar of that User using UserName

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Requirement: I have to get the username and avatar of a given user in the message

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}avatar `)) {
        message.channel.send(`${message.mentions.username}'s avatar: ${message.mentions.avatarURL}`)
}
```

**I got an error:**

> undefined's avatar: undefined

Answer (score 1):

The `mentions` property on the `message` event object returns a [MessageMentions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) object, not a user object, which is what you seem to be expecting.

The reason for this is you may be mentioning more than 1 user in a message, so this object passes you an array of the relevant users. The following code will fetch the first user mentioned.

```
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}avatar `)) {
    let firstUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    message.channel.send(`${firstUser.username}'s avatar: ${firstUser.avatarURL}`) 
}
```

Comment: This is instead giving me an error 

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined"

Comment: @Trueace004 It should be `let firstUser = message.mentions.users.first()`

Comment: @Trueace004 Please accept this answer by clicking on the tick (v) on the left. When you do that, the question is marked as answered ;)